# How to add column to dataframe after converting from json?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

This is my code.

```py
def activeingredients(json):
    dfai= pd.io.json.json_normalize(json)
    print(dfai)
    return
activeingredients(jsonstr['results'][0]['drug'][0]['active_ingredients'])
```

My output.

| name | dose.denominator_unit |
| --- | --- |
| Diethylcarbamazine, Oxibendazole | Unknown |

I have a unique number from the same nested json that corresponds with each drug report.
How do I add my identifying variable to my function.

I have this so far.

```py
def activeingredients(json):
    dfai= pd.io.json.json_normalize(json)
    id = df. iloc[:, 1] 
    print(id)
    print(type(id))
    print(dfai)
    return
        
activeingredients(jsonstr['results'][0]['drug'][0]['active_ingredients'])
activeingredients(jsonstr['results'])
```

need to join on unique id in function and keep all data

I want it to look like this.

| name | dose.denominator_unit | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Diethylcarbamazine, Oxibendazole | Unknown | 1682 |

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to share a sample json?

Assuming the json looks like below.  (from description)

```
  json_text =  '{
    "1" : {"name" : "Diethylcarbamazine, Oxibendazole", "dose" : "unknown"},
    "2" : {"name" : "ABC, Oxibendazole", "dose" : "unknown"},
    "3" : {"name" : "DEF, Oxibendazole", "dose" : "unknown"}
    }'
```

You need to perform the following steps.

```
import json 

list_of_dicts= []
json_dict = json.loads(json_text)
for k, v in json_dict.items() :
    d = {"id" :k}
    d.update(v)
    list_of_dicts.append(d) 
   
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

Hope this works. Thanks.